# Prestashop - Edit Theme - How do I replace a product name?

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm not a PHP programmer, but I'm working in a Prestashop project.

The problem is: 
 - The product is named as: Carolina Herrera 212 Sexy 3.4oz
Where Carolina Herrera is the brand, 212 Sexy is the product and 3.4oz is the size.

I want to show just the product and size, and remove the brand from the product name.

In the template page I have the code

```
<span class="grid-name">
    {$product.name|truncate:45:'...'|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}
</span>
```

$product.name is the variable I want to change.
$product.manufacturer_name is the variable with just the name of the brand.

How can I apply a replace in $product.name to replace manufacturer_name for nothing?

Something like [IN ASP]

```
Replace($product.name, $product.manufacturer_name, '')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prestashop use Smarty as template engine. So according to Smarty documentation :

```
{$product.name|replace:$product.manufacturer_name:''}
```

You can apply more function if needed :

```
{$product.name|replace:$product.manufacturer_name:''|truncate:45:'...'|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. This solved my problem. Thank you!